# Java - Refactor almost identical methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a method which looks something like this:

```
private void method(final Param one, final Param two) {
    Code Block
    CallToAnotherMethod() 
}
```

This method is called from 2 places. In one of the places, I want to call the entire method as is. In the second place, I want to only execute the `Code Block` but not the `CallToAnotherMethod()`.

How should I go about refactoring this? Implementing 2 methods with 99% of the same code does not seem elegant.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Add a third parameter, e.g. `boolean doAdditionalProcessing`, and use that to determine whether the `CallToAnotherMethod()` should be executed.

Comment: you could pass another argument that decides which code to execute.

Comment: put this 99% of the code in its own method.

Comment: Do **not** add a parameter that determines what code will be executed. That's bad design, breaking among other things the simple responsibility principle.

Comment: @Kayaman I agree in principal, but method parameters are often used in conditionals inside a method. What the OP should do here is hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @GriffeyDog there's a difference between "using parameters in conditionals inside a method", and "using parameters to determine the method's logic". The `boolean` parameter is a tell tale sign, whether it's called `performSpecialHandling`, `doAdditionalProcessing` or `fixDesignProblemWithMoreBadDesign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any insight in the actual code, it is hard to judge it properly. As with any generic question, we can only provide a generic answer.

```
private void method(final Param one, final Param two) {
    methodForCodeBlock(one, two);
    callToAnotherMethod() 
}

private void methodForCodeBlock(final Param one, final Param two) {
    // code block here
}

private void callToAnotherMethod() {
    ...
}
```

To only execute the code block, call `methodForCodeBlock(...)`. To execute everything, call `method(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have

```
private void method(final Param one, final Param two) {
    codeBlockMethod() 
    CallToAnotherMethod() 
}


private void method2(final Param one, final Param two) {
    CallToAnotherMethod() 
}

private void codeBlockMethod() {
    Code Block
}
```

Comment: Method names are inconsistent.